# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: loginpackage/LoginServlet (wrong name: WEB-INF/classes/loginpackage/LoginServlet)

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I will try to be as specific and give as much info as possible.

I have tomcat 7 installed on my computer at C:\myproject\tomcat

I have JDK 1.7.0_04 installed at C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0_04

JRE_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04

CLASSPATH = C:\myproject\tomcat\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\myproject\tomcat\bin\tomcat-juli.jar

In the jdk1.7.0_04\jre\lib\ext folder I have the file servlet-api.jar, which I beleive is needed to run any servlets.

In my C:\myproject\tomcat\conf\web.xml file I have the tags

servlet tag

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>loginpackage.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

servlet-mapping tag

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I believe that is needed so localhost:9999/javawork/LoginServlet can be found.

I have a web app called javawork located at C:\myproject\tomcat\webapps\javawork

In there I have a folder test_login, which contains my JSP files, including LoginPage.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1256" pageEncoding="windows-1256"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">
        <title>Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="../LoginServlet">
            Please enter your username      
            <input type="text" name="un"/><br>      
            Please enter your password
            <input type="password" name="pw"/>
            <input type="submit" value="submit">            
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

In javawork I have a WEB-INF folder with lib and classes folders, I have a couple jar files in the lib folder with my oracle driver.  In the classes folder I have a loginpackage folder, and inside that I have my LoginServlet.java file and LoginServlet.class file. I compiled it using Eclipse IDE, which puts the .class files into a folder javawork/bin/WEB-INF/classes/loginpackage folder, and I move the .class files into the main WEB-INF folder structure to be in the same directory as the .java files.

LoginServlet.java:

```
package loginpackage;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class LoginServlet
 */

public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        try
        {       

             UserBean user = new UserBean();
             user.setUserName(request.getParameter("un"));
             user.setPassword(request.getParameter("pw"));

             user = UserDAO.login(user);

             if (user.isValid())
             {

                  HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);   
                  session.setMaxInactiveInterval(60);
                  session.setAttribute("currentSessionUser",user); 
                  session.setAttribute("sessUserName", user.getUsername());
                  session.setAttribute("userID",user.getUserID());
                  response.sendRedirect("userlogged.jsp"); //logged-in page             
             }

             else 
                  response.sendRedirect("invalidlogin.jsp"); //error page 
        } 


        catch (Throwable theException)      
        {
             System.out.println(theException); 
        }
    }//end doGet
}//End LoginServlet Class
```

I open a command prompt and go to C:\myproject\tomcat\bin and run the startup file so the tomcat server is running.

I go to `http://localhost:9999/javawork/test_login/LoginPage.jsp`, which loads up fine.  I enter the username and password into the boxes and click the submit button.  It tries to go to `http://localhost:9999/javawork/LoginServlet?un=u&pw=p` (u and p are what I enter), and I get the following error:
exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: loginpackage/LoginServlet (wrong name: WEB-INF/classes/loginpackage/LoginServlet)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2889)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1170)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:461)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:309)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1812)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I think everything lines up properly, so I am not sure why I get this error.  Please, any help would be greatly appreciated, bc I have been stuck on this for over a day, and need to make it work to move on to the next part of my task at work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You said:

> In my C:\myproject\tomcat\conf\web.xml file I have the tags...

Well for my knowledge you have to enter the `mapping` values of a servlet in your project's `web.xml` not the one located in the path you have given.

If you have not created the `web.xml` in `YourProject/WEB-INF/web.xml` then create it first and enter the values:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>loginpackage.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

servlet-mapping tag

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

in it. ([Here is a simple `web.xml` file](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/java/web_application/web_xml.html)) Good luck!

Comment: you actually can place it in the web.xml file right on the server.  I took my project out of Eclipse bc I need to use a different file structure for my job.  The file structure I use actually lets all web apps on my server use the same web.xml file, so this works.  But compiling in Eclipse does seem to require that you place the web.xml file directly inside the project.

Comment: Well its a good practice to have a personal `web.xml` for each new project separately whether you are on an IDE or just working out through notepad.

Answer (score 1):

You should have servlet entries in your project's C:\myproject\tomcat\webapps\javawo\WEB-INF\web.xml file not in C:\myproject\tomcat\conf\web.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was.

"I compiled it using Eclipse IDE, which puts the .class files into a folder javawork/bin/WEB-INF/classes/loginpackage folder, and I move the .class files into the main WEB-INF folder structure to be in the same directory as the .java files."

When I compiled the classes in Eclipse and the .class files were placed into the specified folder, it set a path somewhere within the class.  So when I moved the files to the folder I need them to be in, it would not find them because it was looking for them in the folder they compiled to.  I had to use the javac compiler from a command prompt to compile my .class files into the same folder as the .java source files.  Once I did that, I was able to run my code.

Now I just need to play around with Eclipse to make it compile my files to the proper folders, so I do not have to manually compile them with javac.

Comment: Please mark this as answer if this solved your question.